# Java Ejb Schedule is not being triggered

Tags: java, schedule

I have a @Schedule method that i'm trying to debug, but is not being triggered:

```
@Singleton
public class FileScheduler {

    @EJB
    private DaoFactory daoFactory;

    @Schedule(persistent = false, minute = "1")
    public void FilesSubmited() throws EmailException {
        System.out.println("Init");
      
    }
```

What could be the reason that the schedule is not being activated?

Comment: This schedule will trigger every hour at `xx:01`, meaning at `08:01`, `09:01`,... Perhaps you want to test it with `minute = "*/1"` so it runs every minute? More details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html)

Comment: Do you have right class: import javax.ejb.Singleton ?

Comment: Yes , i have:   Maven: javax:javaee-api:6.0

Answer (score 0):

You probably need [@Startup](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Startup.html). And if you want it to run every minute, the expression should be `"*/1"` ([more about expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html)):

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class FileScheduler {

    @EJB
    private DaoFactory daoFactory;

    @Schedule(persistent = false, minute = "*/1")
    public void FilesSubmited() throws EmailException {
        System.out.println("Init");
      
    }
}
```

The EJB container initiates the singleton session bean upon application deployment if the singleton is annotated with the `@Startup` annotation.